# Wordpress logo not clickable only on some pages

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with my wordpress website: semcamp.university

On homepage logo is clickable and everything is ok, but on some other pages for example: http://semcamp.university/warsztaty-analytics-fundamentals/ or 
semcamp.university/warsztaty-adwords-professional/ is not and I have no idea what's going on. Wha't more it is working on page semcamp.university/warsztaty-usability-fundamentals/ a it confused me a lot. Please help me!

Thank you guys! :)

Comment: Looks like it's your navigation menu. If you change the display:block!important and uncheck it, the menu disappears and the logo is clickable. If you inspect the nav menu, you'll see it has full width. Maybe try making it inline-block, and aligning right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below style:

```
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: I added two last line to my style .navbar-brand and no it works. Thank You so much :)